# Sync Framework. Replace PK in SQL Server CE 4.0

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I try to upload from two SQL Server CE 4.0 to main SQL Server this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Patient] 
(
  [Guid] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL ROWGUIDCOL DEFAULT NEWID() 
, [Id] int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL Primary key
)
```

Here Guid used to be PK for sync, so in Provision method I do (looking [here](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/part-3-synchronizing-tables-where-client-and-server-primary-keys-are-different/)):

```
var clientScope = new DbSyncScopeDescription(scope);
var patTable = SqlCeSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Patient", clientConn);
docTable.GlobalName = docTbl;
clientScope.Tables.Add(patTable);

// remove the identity column PK since we dont need to sync it
patTable.Columns["Guid"].IsPrimaryKey = true;
patTable.Columns.Remove(patTable.Columns["Id"]);

var clientProvision = new SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning(clientConn, clientScope);
clientProvision.ObjectPrefix = prefix;

if (!clientProvision.ScopeExists(scope))
{
    clientProvision.Apply(); // <- key not found exception in Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
    Console.WriteLine("Provisioned");
}
```

And same for server provision. Server provisioning goes fine, but client there is `KeyNotFoundException`.

Is that the case when SQL Server Compact 4.0 does not support data replication with SQL Server using Sync Framework (even after setting assembly binding redirect) or error in my code?

Comment: what do you see on the PKColumns property of the table when you debug?

Comment: as expected [0] {PK Column Name: "Guid" Type: "uniqueidentifier"}

Comment: try moving clientScope.Tables.Add(patTable); just before this line var clientProvision = new SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning(clientConn, clientScope);

Comment: it looks like this will not work with the SqlCeSyncProvider. Somehow, it's re-querying the table to get PK stats during provisioning and finds the old PK but then it can't find it in the scope definition.